# The itmes of Xamarin.Forms ListView are not visible

Tags: listview, xamarin

I tried to run ListViewList example of chapter19 in the [github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples).

I updated NuGet package to the latest version.

But the itmes of Xamarin.Forms ListView are not visible on Android and UWP platforms. I have not tested it on iOS.

I have not modified any code. Why do not the items appear?

Answer (score 0):

Causes:
The datasource are type of Color, not the ones can be displayed, like string, image, etc.

```
    listView.ItemsSource = new List<Color>
    {
        Color.Aqua, Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Fuchsia,
        Color.Gray, Color.Green, Color.Lime, Color.Maroon,
        Color.Navy, Color.Olive, Color.Pink, Color.Purple,
        Color.Red, Color.Silver, Color.Teal, Color.White, Color.Yellow
    };
```

If you modified the code above to

```
    listView.ItemsSource = new List<String>
    {
        "aaaaaa","bbbbb","cccccc"
    };
```

Then you would see the items in the list.

Comment: I know that ListView uses ToString method of each item in the collection when display items in the ListView.